# Топ 3 товара в магазине

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`LIMIT` вернул мне первые 3 записи, как сделать чтобы он вернуть ТОП 3 продаваемых товаров? То есть в данном примере он должен был показать Xbox, Playstation и Лего

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте к Вашему запросу сортировку:

```
SELECT name,sell_toys FROM products_test ORDER BY sell_toys DESC LIMIT 3
```